# Getting error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instances found of configserver (config-server)

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-config

I'm trying to register a spring-cloud config server with my eureka discovery server, however I'm encountering this error:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instances found of configserver (config-server)

application.yml (config-server):

```
spring:
  application:
    name: config-server
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri:  https://github.com/danielturato/microservices-config.git
          username: *******
          password: *******
          clone-on-start: true

server:
  port: 8888

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
    appname: config-server
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:1111/eureka/
```

bootstrap.yml (eureka-server):

```
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka-server

server:
  port: 1111

eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:1111/eureka/
```

bootstrap.yml (eureka-client):

```
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka-client
  cloud:
    config:
      discovery:
        enabled: true
        service-id: config-server
```

eureka-client.yml (eureka-client config found on config server repo):

```
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:1111/eureka/

server:
  port: 8081
```

The config server itself works as when running, it fetches the config for the eureka client. However, every few mins I receive this error and the config server itself never registers:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instances found of configserver (config-server)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServerInstanceProvider.getConfigServerInstances(ConfigServerInstanceProvider.java:48) ~[spring-cloud-config-client-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration.refresh(DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration.java:101) [spring-cloud-config-client-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration.heartbeat(DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration.java:92) [spring-cloud-config-client-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration.onApplicationEvent(DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration.java:82) [spring-cloud-config-client-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) [spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) [spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) [spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:402) [spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:408) [spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:359) [spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.onCacheRefreshed(CloudEurekaClient.java:123) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:999) [eureka-client-1.9.12.jar:1.9.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.refreshRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1497) [eureka-client-1.9.12.jar:1.9.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$CacheRefreshThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1464) [eureka-client-1.9.12.jar:1.9.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_211]
```

From this error, I maybe wrong, but I feel like there's a problem with the config server however I'm really not sure what's wrong. See above for the application.yml file and see below the Application class & pom file:

ConfigServerApplication:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableConfigServer
public class ConfigServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

pom.xml for ConfigServer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.danielturato</groupId>
    <artifactId>config-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>config-server</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

config-server logs:

```
2019-09-12 17:14:25.311  INFO 1656 --- [           main] c.d.c.ConfigServerApplication            : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-09-12 17:14:25.983  INFO 1656 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=5638ff1e-e195-3b5c-a934-c721843f315c
2019-09-12 17:14:26.042  INFO 1656 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3fdd8981] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-09-12 17:14:26.219  INFO 1656 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8888 (http)
2019-09-12 17:14:26.237  INFO 1656 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-09-12 17:14:26.238  INFO 1656 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.24]
2019-09-12 17:14:26.340  INFO 1656 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-09-12 17:14:26.340  INFO 1656 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1019 ms
2019-09-12 17:14:28.719  INFO 1656 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-09-12 17:14:29.162  INFO 1656 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2019-09-12 17:14:29.245  INFO 1656 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8888 (http) with context path ''
2019-09-12 17:14:29.247  INFO 1656 --- [           main] c.d.c.ConfigServerApplication            : Started ConfigServerApplication in 5.097 seconds (JVM running for 6.359)
2019-09-12 17:14:47.055  INFO 1656 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-09-12 17:14:47.055  INFO 1656 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-09-12 17:14:47.061  INFO 1656 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 6 ms
2019-09-12 17:14:47.769  INFO 1656 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] o.s.c.c.s.e.NativeEnvironmentRepository  : Adding property source: file:/C:/Users/danie/AppData/Local/Temp/config-repo-6536884673987435552/eureka-client.yml
```

If anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong, any help would be great. Thanks.

**Conclusion**

I've come to the conclusion that there was either something wrong with my project files or my computer as I completed an identical project on my laptop and the project ran completely fine. I have no idea what was wrong still

Comment: No idea. Is that the full bootstrap from eureka client?

Comment: Yes, however I do have config for the client on the config server which I shall include but I believe this doesn't effect the config been registered

Comment: the eureka config can't be on the config server if you are using eureka to find config server. Chicken and egg problem.

Comment: The only eureka settings on the config server was setting the defaultZone for the a eureka-client. I moved that settings to the bootstrap , however I still receive the same error

Comment: what does http://<eurekaserver>/eureka/apps say?

Comment: It just says I have 1 instance running which is the eureka-client

Comment: then config server isn't registered with eureka.

Comment: I have @ EnableDiscoveryClient on the config server main application alongside @ EnableConfigServer

Comment: Do you have the eureka client dependency?

Comment: Yes, the only dependencies on the config server application are eureka-client, config-server & spring-boot starter.

Comment: I added the application class , pom file and full error message to see if this will help further but I'm really stuck on why it's not working @spencergibb

Comment: The real problem is that config server isn't registered with eureka. Any logs from config server?

Comment: I've put the logs above in the question, however they look fine to me

Comment: It doesn't to me, there should be logs saying it registered with eureka.

Comment: Well yes, apart from the fact it's not registering there's no indication on why it's not. I replicated the code on another computer and it worked fine which suggest there was something wrong with my project files

Comment: At this point, without a sample project, there's not much else I can do.

Comment: Hey, had the same issue and it turned out to be the name in the config. I renamed the application to `configserver` and it resolved my issue

Answer (score 1):

Hey had the same issue with my setup.

I changed
`spring.application.name: config-server`
..to 
`spring.application.name: configserver`

and the issue went away. I know it's a weird one, but it did the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes you get this error when (spring.cloud.config.discovery.serviceId) this attribute is not present in your yaml/properties file.
I was getting same "No instance found for config-server" error. When I used "serviceId",it got resolved.